# Mi contenedor docker se para al arrancarlo

Tags: docker

me he bajado de **dockerhub** la imagen de bitnami de laravel : https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/laravel

Me he creado un contenedor:

```
docker run [hash] --name laravel_test
```

Arranco el docker:

```
docker start laravel_test
```

Entonces iba a lanzar el comando :

```
docker exec -it laravel_test /bin/bash
```

Y me dice docker:

```
docker  exec -it laravel_test /bin/bash
Error response from daemon: Container 3146ce83a086a6511b1690327ca2f30644b3ef5bbfa04a3773c5ca5c607ce933 is not runnin
```

Es decir, se apaga justo despues de arrancarlo, es un contenedor nuevo de hub oficial y recomendado, no debe de haber nada corrupto entiendo.

Los logs del contenedor son:

```
Fetch the logs of a container                                                                                            
[root@nas ~]# docker logs laravel_test                                                                                   
laravel 13:50:17.21                                                                                                      
laravel 13:50:17.21 Welcome to the Bitnami laravel container                                                             
laravel 13:50:17.22 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-laravel           
laravel 13:50:17.22 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-laravel/issues       
laravel 13:50:17.22                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                         
/opt/bitnami/scripts/laravel/entrypoint.sh: line 28: exec: --: invalid option                                            
exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]                                            
laravel 13:51:40.35                                                                                                      
laravel 13:51:40.35 Welcome to the Bitnami laravel container                                                             
laravel 13:51:40.36 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-laravel           
laravel 13:51:40.36 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-laravel/issues       
laravel 13:51:40.36                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                         
/opt/bitnami/scripts/laravel/entrypoint.sh: line 28: exec: --: invalid option                                            
exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]                                            
laravel 13:52:32.26                                                                                                      
laravel 13:52:32.27 Welcome to the Bitnami laravel container                                                             
laravel 13:52:32.27 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-laravel           
laravel 13:52:32.27 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-laravel/issues       
laravel 13:52:32.27
```

¿Estoy saltandome algun paso o hay algo que debo de tener en cuenta que estoy pasando por alto?

Verbose al ejecutar comando del comentario `docker run -t [hash]`

```
laravel 14:31:09.08
laravel 14:31:09.09 Welcome to the Bitnami laravel container
laravel 14:31:09.09 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-laravel
laravel 14:31:09.09 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-laravel/issues
laravel 14:31:09.09
laravel 14:31:09.10 INFO  ==> ** Running Laravel setup **
laravel 14:31:09.44 INFO  ==> Configuring PHP options
laravel 14:31:09.44 INFO  ==> Setting PHP opcache.enable option
laravel 14:31:09.55 INFO  ==> Setting PHP expose_php option
laravel 14:31:09.63 INFO  ==> Validating settings in LARAVEL_* environment variables...
laravel 14:31:09.73 WARN  ==> Hostname mariadb could not be resolved, this could lead to connection issues
laravel 14:31:09.75 INFO  ==> Creating Laravel application in /app
laravel 14:31:11.26 INFO  ==> Regenerating APP_KEY
laravel 14:31:12.62 Updating dependencies
laravel 14:31:22.43 INFO  ==> Trying to connect to the database server
laravel 14:32:22.80 ERROR ==> Could not connect to the database
```

Comment: Un contenedor se va a detener cuando termine el proceso definido por defecto. Usar `docker run -t [hash]` debería funcionar (a menos que haya un error en el arranque y por eso se esté deteniendo). ¿Modificaste algo de ese docker-compose que bajas de docker hub?

Comment: @Alfabravo acabo de ejecutar el comando que me indicas y ha dado eun error. He actualizado la pregunta con el log verbose que me ha sacado. Parece que no puede conectar a la BD, pero que BD ?

Comment: Pues laravel es un framework PHP, no? Eso debe usar una BD mariadb para la configuración y todueso. De nuevo, el enlace de docker hub que compartes ofrece un docker-compose que no nos has mostrado (supongo que hiciste docker build) y **ahí mismo** dice `check out the available configuration options for the MariaDB container for a more secure deployment.`

Comment: @Alfabravo perfecto, he seguido las instrucciones, me ha creado el servidor y tal, pero no me deja acceder a la app en el puerto que indica el ejemplo. Tampoco entiendo si es que tengo que crear yo una app en mi maquina anfitrion en el directorio que indica el yml y el docker lo detecta automaticamente o es que lo tengo que hacer desde el docker, en ambos casos no esta laravel por ningun lado. No se como tengo que proceder